# Why can't I find commodities in the auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

Last week I was able to buy gems in the auction house. I bought a few flawless square gems. But now when I search for more nothing comes up, no matter what gem I search for. Is that just because no one is selling them, or is there something wrong with the auction house?

Comment: This is a good Q & A for now, but voting to close as too localized as it's basically a transient server issue that will be corrected soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently Commodity Auctions are down for maintenance, which means right now gems cannot be bought or sold.

> We have temporarily disabled commodity auctions for the gold auction house. Sales of items such as gems and crafting materials have been brisk since the launch and we're currently working on a number of optimizations to improve the speed at which they can be processed. If you happened to have a commodity auction listed prior to this change, you can cancel the listing from the Auctions tab to reclaim the item.
>
> Please note that while commodities are disabled, players who attempt to sell them in the auction house will receive an "auction failed (error 31025)" message.
>
> We recognize that these items are highly desired and are working to make commodities available again as soon as possible. We'll provide further updates within this thread as they become availa

[Source](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149151730?page=1)

Comment: For those wondering why, it's because recently, attempting to buy commodities would often eat your gold but not give you anything in return. It appears the approach taken for buying/selling commodities was simply not scalable enough for the number of players (and the popularity of spamming requests).

Answer (score 2):

If commodities are not showing up when you search in the Auction House, it usually means there is something wrong on Blizzard's end.  Typically, it's one of two things:

- Server maintenance.  Sometimes Blizzard will disable commodities in the Auction House.  Check for announcements on Battle.net
- Heavy server load.  Just keep trying.  Sometimes closing the Auction House interface can help in this instance.

It is *highly* unlikely that nobody is trying to sell commodities.